# Angular and Material Design Light

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, material-design

I'm triyng to implement [MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/) in a simple Angular app.
The issue is that even if I put the MDL javascript file before the angular javascript files MDL components that rely on MDL doesn't work.

This is my scripts order:

```
<script src="js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.swipebox.min.js"></script>
<!-- load angular, ngRoute, ngAnimate -->
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

How can I make other javascript libraries work with angular?

Comment: "Don't work" is a little to vague to answer, can you clarify the issue? Also, if you want angular and material design, why not use the first party `angular-material` library? https://material.angularjs.org/

Comment: I don't want to use material.angular becouse it's a bit complicated for me. Doesn't work becouse angular "blocks" the other javascript

Comment: That brings us back to whats not working? Your question needs to be more detailed if you wanted help. Are elements not rendering? Are you getting console errors? I see you have a jquery plugin but no jquery load in your scripts, that could be it, but you have to help us help you.

Comment: IT's not a issue with that jquery plugin. To be more specific the component that rely on mdl doesn't work, like there is no javascript. For example, the drawer button doesnt trigger, the searchbar don't collapse...

Comment: I think that is not related to my code, but more like a procedure with custom javascript/external js libraries and the way Angular works.

Comment: You've done everything MDL tells you to do on dynamic sites?: http://www.getmdl.io/started/#dynamic

Comment: my experience is, it acts strangely when I use ngRoute with templates, it some how doubles the height of page, hiding footer...

Answer (score 0):

I found this and worked for me

```js
angular.module(...)
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
        });
    });
})
```